# Return type of field from ceneric class with generic method

Tags: java, generics

I have two implemented classes with different return types on their method.

```
abstract class A<S> {
    abstract S value()
}

class B extends A<Integer> {
  @Override
  Integer value() {
    return 10
  }
}

class C extends A<String> {
  @Override
  String value() {
    return "Hello"
  }
}
```

How can I set the return type when calling

```
<T extends A> returnTypeHere getValue(T object) {
    return object.value()
}
```

so when I call it I know the return type

```
getValue(new B()) // return an Integer
```

I tried to somehow access the generic S from class A but without success

```
<T extends A, U extends A.S> U getValue(T object) {
    return object.value()
}
```

Comment: I think you want `<T extends A<S>> S getValue(T object)`?

Comment: More specifically, `<S, T extends A<S>>` if you're missing a generic `S` to work with. Note that generics and single-letter class named mix terribly. I do wonder the value of the `#getValue` method, when you could simply use `#value` directly on the object you're passing to deal with this.